# Nested for loop in Python to get equivalent result

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have two for loops to get the result as below.

First loop:

```
 for row1 in value1:
     print(row1)

The result is:

    A
    B
    C
```

Second loop:

```
 for row2 in value2:
     print(row2)

The result is:

    A
    B
    C
```

The result is expected as below using both the loops:

```
A A
B B
C C
```

I have tried using nested loops:

```
for row1 in value1:
    for row2 in value2:
       print(row1, row2)

The result is coming in as Cartesian values:
A A
A B
A C
B A
B B
B C
C A
C B
C V
```

What can I try next?

Comment: are the lengths of value1 and value2 same?

Comment: Yes it is always same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
value1=['A','B','C']
value2=['A','B','C']

for x,y in enumerate(value1):
    print(value2[x],y)

A A
B B
C C
```

Or

```
for x,y in zip(value1,value2):
    print(x,y)

A A
B B
C C
```